# I want to create an quick action button on an object from Apex class which calls a Visualforce page. How will I do this?

Tags: apex, quickaction

I have a scenario where I have to create an Quick Action button on multiple objects which call a VF page. If the admin do this task through Salesforce UI, it is very repetitive and the admin have to manually go through each object and have to create an Quick Action button.
So I want to know how do I make this task to be completed through Apex class?

I was thinking we can use Apex Metadata API, but don't know how to proceed, I couldn't figured out, how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking to create custom metadata via Apex Code.
I am sharing some pseudo code here, you need to be modified to achieve your requirement.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();  
MetadataService.WebLink webLink = new MetadataService.WebLink();

String customizedName = customButtonName.replace(' ','_');

webLink.fullName = objectName+'.'+customizedName;
webLink.availability = 'online';
webLink.displayType = 'button';
webLink.linkType = 'url';
webLink.url = buttonURL;
webLink.encodingKey = 'UTF-8';
webLink.masterLabel = customButtonName;
webLink.openType = 'newWindow';
webLink.position = 'none'; 
webLink.width = 600;    
webLink.protected_x = false;

list<MetadataService.UpsertResult> saveResultList = new list<MetadataService.UpsertResult>();
saveResultList = service.upsertMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { webLink });
```

Please find the reference link here for more learning [Create a Dynamic Detail Page Button For Any sObject using Meta Data](https://hicglobalsolutions.com/blog/create-a-dynamic-detail-page-button-for-any-sobject-using-meta-data/)

Comment: Thanks Virendra, your answer really helped me to proceed with my task. Once again Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Global Quick Action](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_global) that can be applied to all objects at once. Otherwise, you'll find it's probably still faster to add it one at a time than it would be to write the Apex for this. You could also write an SFDX script, which would be easier than relying on Apex code.